# Git: Changes not staging when using git add * -A

Tags: git, staging

Somehow, an .iml file has made its way into my git repo...

Here's how am I trying to get rid of it:

1. I cloned the latest version to a local folder
2. Checked out the branch that I want to merge later into master
3. Deleted myproject.iml (using windows gui)
4. edited .gitignore with extra line: `*.iml`
5. Trying to stage the changes: `git add * -A`
6. Trying to commit: `git commit -m"untrack .iml file and ignore for future commits"`

Problem:

```
On branch mybranch
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   .gitignore
    deleted:    myproject.iml

no changes added to commit
```

Why are they not staged for commit? I thought `-A` would stage deletions too?
And also, in any way, I thought changes (like the one I made to .gitignore) are added to staging area without any special parameters?

It's weird because just before that, I committed a huge 20-file all-nighter, with changes, deletions, additions, branch within branch, all the goodies, with no problems - using the exact same procedure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use '`*`' with the git add command: '`*`' means shell expansion, which, in your case, would *not* include any `.xxx` file/folder.

Simply use:

```
git add .
```

(Note the '`.`')
No need for `-A`, which is the default anyway, [since Git 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19419348/6309).

For more on this, see "[Difference between `.` (dot) and `*` (asterisk) wildcards in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53509019/6309)".

Comment: this is what happens when I copy paste from SO! Let me fix what I was doing (by copy-pasting yours ;) BTW, I did read the manual but things didn't quite sink in, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

the command is "git add . " ('.' enstead of '*')  and no need for -A