# Best level in hierarchy to create repository for Multi-project development area

Tags: git

I have the following heirarchy:

```
BigProductName/
    code/
        .gitignore suitable for Linux C++ development
        Project1/
            Makefile; all .cpp, .h, etc. for this project
        Project2/
            Makefile; all .cpp, .h, etc. for this project
        Project3/
            Makefile; all .cpp, .h, etc. for this project
        vs2022/
            .gitignore suitable for Visual Studio
            FirmName.sln
            various Visual Studio files
    distribution/
    Distribution1.0/
    Distribution1.0.zip
```

All git controlled files are under code.  the distribution files are my output and not to be controlled.*

**Question:** Do I run `git init` under `FirmName` followed by `add code`, or do I run `git init` inside `code` and if so, do I then do `git add *` or `git add .`?

* Extraneous detail that is tangential to the question but may help to answer: running a make inside the code directory automatically produces the `distribution` heirarchy: copies docs, headers, example code, as well as the binaries and libraries resulting from the make.  Doing a build under `vs2022` of `BigProduct.sln` likewise populates the Windows subdirectories under distribution.  Periodically, a release is created by simply renaming `distribution` to say `Distribution1.0` and zipping it up.  This is why we have a code directory under Git's control, side by side with other directories and files that aren't: they're the output of the build.  They're not under source code control because they aren't source code.  Yet, they are logically grouped with the code tree that made them and so are grouped tightly with it.

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" organization of source files and repositories is in significant part a matter of opinion, and hence not answerable on StackOverflow.

The place (folder or directory, whatever term you prefer) where you run `git init` is where Git will create the hidden `.git` folder that will *store* the repository.  This becomes the top level of the *working tree*.  So given the image above, if you were in the `FirmName` directory (folder) and ran `git init` there, you'd get:

```
FirmName/
    .git/
    code/
        .gitignore suitable for Linux C++ development
        Project1/
            Makefile; all .cpp, .h, etc. for this project
        Project2/
            Makefile; all .cpp, .h, etc. for this project
        Project3/
            Makefile; all .cpp, .h, etc. for this project
        vs2022/
            .gitignore suitable for Visual Studio
            FirmName.sln
            various Visual Studio files
    distribution
    Distribution1.0
    Distribution1.1
```

(I don't know if `distribution` is a file or directory; I left off the trailing slash that would mark it as a directory here.)  Note that Git never stores any directories (folders) at all: it only stores *files*, so this `.git` would store files named `code/Project1/.gitignore` and `code/Project2/.gitignore`, for instance.

With this structure, checking out a specific commit would populate the entire working tree—everything in `code/` and all the `distribution*` files, unless those files are also ignored via a `.gitignore` at the same level as the `code/` directory, or are otherwise untracked.<sup>1</sup>

On the other hand, if you change into the `code` directory and run `git init` there, you'd get:

```
FirmName/
    code/
        .git/
        .gitignore suitable for Linux C++ development
        Project1/
            Makefile; all .cpp, .h, etc. for this project
        Project2/
            Makefile; all .cpp, .h, etc. for this project
        Project3/
            Makefile; all .cpp, .h, etc. for this project
        vs2022/
            .gitignore suitable for Visual Studio
            FirmName.sln
            various Visual Studio files
    distribution
    Distribution1.0
    Distribution1.1
```

Note how the top level of the working tree is now the `code/` directory itself, and the Git repository will contain the file `.gitignore` and various `Project1/*` files.  It will not contain files named `code/Project1/*`, but rather files named `Project1/*`: the same *contents* but under different *names*.

This means you can create a separate `.git` directory under `distribution/` if that's subdirectory.  You can also create a `.git` under `FirmName/`, but since a Git repository cannot hold another Git repository,<sup>2</sup> any attempt to store `code/.git` into the higher-level Git repository winds up storing a *gitlink* instead: that's half of a submodule, and not useful without the other half, so then you must investigate submodules, or as many call them, *sob*-modules (they make their users cry).

As to `git add .` vs `git add *`:

- `git add .` tells Git: *read the current directory (recursively as needed) and add all the files you find, modulo skipping untracked files that are also ignored*.
- `git add *` tells Git: *read the named files and/or directories, and add those*.  Untracked files now cause a complaint, and by default are not added.  There's a complication here though.

  - If you're using a Unix-like shell (bash, zsh, or any of the many similar shells), the *shell* expands `*` to the various names, and the *shell* normally skips over "dot-files" such as `.gitignore`.  That's normally *not* what you want.
  - If you're using the old `CMD.EXE` on Windows, this *does not* expand the `*`, so Git sees the literal text `*` and does its own expansion.  This *does* include dot-files by default.

  For more about this, see [Difference between . (dot) and * (asterisk) wildcards in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53508683/1256452).  (What PowerShell does, I have no idea.)

The upshot of all of this is that `git add .` or `git add --all` is probably want you want, most of the time, as it works everywhere.

---

<sup>1</sup>The tracked/untracked-ness state of a file is not determined by whether the file is listed in a `.gitignore`, but rather by whether the file is *in Git's index*.  However, listing a file in `.gitignore` tends to *prevent* the file from going *into* Git's index, so that *tends* to cause it to *stay* untracked, if it's already untracked.  The problem here is that a tracked file is tracked regardless of whether it's listed in `.gitignore`, so if it's tracked, it tends to stay tracked.

<sup>2</sup>This is an administrative restriction, not something inherent to the internal Git data structures, but it's still true.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed response.  git add * clearly is wrong, since (on Linux) this won't pick up the critical dot file `.gitignore`.  I see that now.  I have added / to demark directories, along with a footnote detailing the non-Git files in the directory.